# Will google penalize my pages if I will hide by default the main page content?

Tags: google, seo

I've read some similar questions but the mine is about a particular case.

I need to hide the "main page content" as default, visible on user's request using javascript. This is lot of text - about 500-1000 words for every document.

The secondary page content (schematic data, lists, images) will be visible as default.

That's the solution that fits the needs of my customer.

Will a site made like this be penalized?

EDIT: The "main body text" is the text that should appear in search engine's results and it contains the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it hidden via CSS then you use Javascript to show it, that is generally fine. Search engines may give slightly less weight to the content that is hidden, but you are unlikely to be penalised as there are many legitimate uses for this kind of thing like menus.

If the content is not part of the page at all but loaded by AJAX then that loaded content will not be indexed at all by search engines, but you definitely will not get penalised at all.

Answer (score 0):

Google Bots and alikes are not making the difference with hidden via JavaScript content. It depend on the method and if the crawled page without Js is differing too much from the one for your visitors, read penality.

Checkout Google Webmaster tools : fetch as Googlebot to see how they see your pages.

" On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want. On the Dashboard, underDiagnostics, click Fetch as Googlebot."

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

Worth reading about hidden content

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353